# Disabling attribute inheritance / set component options using script setup and Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-script-setup

When using script setup syntax with Typescript in Vue 3, how can I set a component's options to [disable attribute inheritance](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance)?

JavaScript code:

```
app.component('date-picker', {
  inheritAttrs: false,
  // [..]
})
```

Script setup with Typescript:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
// how can I set inheritAttrs here?
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution here:
https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#usage-alongside-normal-script

> `<script setup>` can be used **alongside** normal `<script>`. A normal `<script>` may be needed in cases where you need to:
>
> Declare options that cannot be expressed in `<script setup>`, for
> example **inheritAttrs** or custom options enabled via plugins.

So this did the job:

```
<script lang="ts">
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
}
</script>
```